# const call operator calling bound non-const member function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

The following code compiles fine on every compiler I tried (gcc 4.9.2, clang 3.6 and VS 2015). However VS 2013 update 4 craps out with the error I will detail below. Is this a bug in the compiler?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename Func>
struct Bar
{
    Func f_;
    Bar(Func f) : f_(f) { }
    void operator()() const
    {
        f_();
    }
};

template<typename T>
void Baz(T const& t)
{
    Bar<T> b(t);
    b();
}

struct Foo 
{ 
    Foo()
    {
        auto r = std::bind(&Foo::DoFoo, this);
        Baz(r);
    }
    void DoFoo() { std::cout << "Doing Foo!\n"; } 
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    return 0;
}
```

Error listing follows:

```
1>doodle.cpp(15): error C3848: expression having type 'const std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),void,Foo,>,Foo *const >' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),void,Foo,>,Foo *const >::operator ()<>(void)'
1>          doodle.cpp(14) : while compiling class template member function 'void Bar<T>::operator ()(void) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),void,Foo,>,Foo *const >
1>          ]
1>          doodle.cpp(23) : see reference to function template    instantiation 'void Bar<T>::operator ()(void) const' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),void,Foo,>,Foo *const >
1>          ]
1>          doodle.cpp(22) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Bar<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),void,Foo,>,Foo *const >
1>          ]
1>          doodle.cpp(31) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void Baz<std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),void,Foo,>,Foo *const >>(const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Foo::* )(void),void,Foo,>,Foo *const >
1>          ]
```

I thought it wanted DoFoo() to be a const member function but fixing that didn't help.

Comment: It does compile if I change it to: `std::function<void()> r = std::bind(&Foo::DoFoo, this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a VS2013 compiler bug and there are 2 ways to work around it:

Use std::function instead of auto to store a call to a member function

```
std::function<void()> r = std::bind(&Foo::DoFoo, this);
```

Or remove const from function call operator() in Bar

```
template<typename Func>
struct Bar
{
    Func f_;
    Bar(Func f) : f_(f) { }
    void operator()() // const
    {
        f_();
    }
};
```

Comment: operator() is out of my control. Explicitly specifying the return type works!