# Storing any lambda as a common Callback object in a vector

Tags: c++, function, lambda

I have a dream. That I can store lambda expressions passed to a function in a vector as objects wrapped in a class.
These are then run at a given point later and if their have a return value, it is obtained.

I've been trying find a way to do this, e.g. my other post hit a standstill [Vector with objects that have function pointers of varying type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53241666/vector-with-objects-that-have-function-pointers-of-varying-type)

The reason I want it this way is so that it is as dynamic and easy to use in any scenario as possible.
In the current case, it's to be used in evolutionary algorithms that perform tasks across separate processes and memory spaces.

Is my dream unfeasible, or bad design? Do you know a better way? I've been at this for days without having anything that compiles.

I'd be grateful to be pointed in the right direction.

Basically something along these lines:

```
    std::vector<CallbackJob> myCallbackList;
    std::vector<CallbackJobResult> myCallbackResultList;

    Callback myCB = make_callback( [&]{ return Task->Test("I return boolean"); } );
    Callback myCB2 = make_callback( [&]{ return Foo("I return doubles"); } );

    CallbackJob job1("name1", myCB, 1);
    CallbackJob job2("name2", myCB2, 5);

    myCallbackList.push_back(job1);
    myCallbackList.push_back(job2);

    for(auto &i : myCallbackList) {
    // maybe need to check if it has a return value, embed it into the callback object itself?
        myCallbackResultList.push_back( i.callback() );  
    }
```

Comment: Are all of your callbacks nullary? How are the returned values of various types to be dispatched exactly?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

Comment: note that nothing comes for free, so if you want it "as dynamic and easy to use in any scenario as possible" you will have to pay a price. Just as an example, it is considerably simpler if your callbacks take no parameters (or all the same parameters)

Comment: It's doable, but you should provide a more detailed description. What is `CallbackJobResult`, something similar to `std::any`? Do you want it to be possible to store callbacks with different parameter sets in a single vector? Do you need parameters for your callbacks at all?

Comment: People are always asking how to  store stuff of varying types in containers. What would you *do* with these values? Can you please show some (pseudo)code that goes over the container and actually uses what is stored there?

Comment: @user463035818 You're right, and it would be easier to go that route, but this evolutionary algorithm is set to work in different contexts, so the callbacks it does must be equally dynamic for it to be user-friendly. Of course ditch the user-friendliness and it's easy to write, but annoying to expand on for other users, I guess.

Comment: @n.m. The values, or results in this case are simple types such as bool, ints, that relay progress made by the callback, or state. Depending on these values, the evolutionary algorithm and its master thread will decide what to do.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I guess you are right. The CallbackJobResult can be any (most likely a primitive type ala int or string). I want to store these in the same container so that no matter the type of result, they can all be iterated together. And I would need a way to know the type as a field so that the process can deterime how to use it.

Comment: If you know beforehand the full list of types to be returned, you need a *sum type*. C++ doesn't have real sum types, but std::any (or boost::any) can be used this way. If you don't know all the types, how will the program decide what to do?

Comment: Wait, I forgot that C++ does have std::variant (or you can use boost::variant if your compiler is too old).

Answer (score 1):

You can use *type erasure*, for instance `std::any` and `std::function`, to store lambdas and their resulting values in vectors:

```
std::vector<std::function<std::any()>> functions;
functions.emplace_back([]{ return std::any(1.0); });
functions.emplace_back([]{ return std::any(true); });

std::vector<std::any> results;
for (auto & f : functions)
  results.emplace_back(f());
```

The question is how to process the elements of `results`, since you need to know their types to cast them with `std::any_cast`. In this example, you can use, e.g.:

```
for (const auto & r : results)
  if (r.type() == typeid(double))
    std::cout << std::any_cast<double>(r);
  else if (r.type() == typeid(bool))
    std::cout << std::any_cast<bool>(r);
```

Also note that this will work only if all lambdas have either no parameters or, eventually, parameters of the same type.

Comment: Using std::variant would solve the problem of not knowing which type is stored in the result, of course at the cost that the possbile result types will be somewhat more limited.

Comment: @GSIO01 That's another option; might be worth writing a separate answer.

Comment: Using `std::any::type()` is also a nice way to do it. Totally forgot std::any had that method.

Comment: I really like this answer, but is std::any from C++17? I can use up to C++14 features in our environment which is VS2013.

Comment: Edit to my prev comment: Give me some moments to test this. I am upgrading to VS2017 to see if this works as intended. If it does I might stick with it.